# Errors only in release mode (Windows store app C# / XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have an app that builds fine in debug mode. When I try to build for release it shows around 30 errors, from 2 types. First it says:

> The name "CustomButton" does not exist in the namespace "using:XXX.Controls".

So basically it doesn't recognize all of my converters.

Also it pops an error like this:

> 'XXX.Pages.Upload' does not contain a definition for 'Channel_Click' and no extension method 
>   'Channel_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'XXX.Pages.Upload' could be found (are you 
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't even have a Channel_Click function! It's far gone from both the XAML and C#, and yet the error still pops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried each of these?

Run a Build->Clean and a Build->Rebuild All.

Restart Visual Studio.

Check your solution configuration and make sure all of your projects are building in Release mode.

Check for any mistakes with conditional compilation symbols. some of the namespaces or code will only compile in debug mode and when you switch to release the compiler won't look at anything in the block.

```
#IF DEBUG
...
#ENDIF
```

Comment: I already solved this by updating an old library reference and then rebuilt and cleaned all my code. However I'm marking this answer as correct just for the good advice.